# Could not read cache value from registry.bin [ANDROID STUDIO]

Tags: android, caching, android-studio

I recently simply deleted my cache memory from the folder %temp% (I read it somewhere deleting content of %temp% improve performane of PC) 
After that when I open my projects in Android studio its showing error message

> Error:Could not read cache value from 'C:\Users\PEACE.gradle\daemon\2.8\registry.bin'.

and the project cannot be further executed :(

How to registry.bin file ?
I have got noting  in recycle bin .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Start
2. Type "cmd" + enter
3. cd to C:\Users\PEACE.gradle\daemon\2.8\
4. Ctrl + A
5. Delete All
6. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

just go **C:\Users\PEACE.gradle\daemon\2.8** directory and delete all files on that directory. then restart Android Studio. that should work

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting everything, I would delete C:\Users\PEACE.gradle\daemon\2.8\registry.bin.lock

Linux
Open terminal.
Execute:

> rm /home/username/.gradle/daemon/{gradle version}/registry.bin.lock

Windows 
Open cmd
Execute

> del C:\Users\UserProfile.gradle\daemon{gradle
>   version}\registry.bin.lock

Answer (score 2):

1. Press Windows-Key + R to open run
2. Type .gradle to open gradle folder
3. Delete daemon folder or folder witch named your gradle version (2.8)
4. Go back to android-studio and press Try Again at the top of your
   editor

Answer (score 2):

For Mac, use the following command:

```
rm /users/{username}/.gradle/daemon/6.5.1/registry.bin.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `%userprofile%\.gradle\daemon` and delete either all of the folders, or just the one causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Go To User -> Select user -> Gradle -> Daemon -> select version then select all and delete all

Then restart android studio.